# Hiding copy constructors for abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, copy-constructor, static-analysis

I have an abstract base class that has some virtual methods and a virtual destructor. I want to make the copy constructor and the assignment operator of the base class (and the derived class) as private so I can hide them and the static analysis tool (klockwork) cannot flag it. This is my code snippet:

```
class Parent: public mainParentClassIDontCareAbout
{
 public:
         Parent (int a);
         virtual ~Parent ();
 protected:
         void doSomething(); 
      .
      .
 private:
          // Hide assignment operator and copy constructor
         Parent (const Parent&) {};
         Parent operator= (const Parent&) {return *this;};

 } // end of parent class definition

class Child : public Parent
{
 public:
         Child (void *x, int y, bool z);
         ~Child ();
 protected:
           .
           .
           .
 private:
          // Hide assignment operator and copy constructor
         Child (const Child&) {};
         Child operator= (const Child&) {return *this;};

 } // end of parent class definition
```

However, I get a compile time error as:

```
invalid abstract return type for member function ‘Lib::Parent Lib::Parent::operator=(const Lib::Parent&)’
```

I want to hide the assignment operator and copy constructor. Is this not a valid behavior when we have a virtual destructor or are there any solutions if I want to have the same scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment operator should return a reference:

```
Parent & operator= (const Parent&) {return *this;}
       ^
```

and likewise for `Child`. Alternatively, they could return nothing, if you don't care about chaining assignments.

Yours tries to return a copy of the object which, in the case of `Parent` is impossible because `Parent` is abstract and can't be instantiated.

Comment: Should that be true for the copy constructor as well ?
Parent & (cosnt Parent&) {}; ?

Comment: @noobcoder: No, constructors don't return anything. They're declared as if they have the same name as the class they construct.

Comment: +1 There is an issue though, the code won't compile as it is (after you add the reference to the return type of `operator=`), because there is no default ctor for `Parent`, and the copy ctor of `Child` will fail (it doesn't know how to instantiate the `Parent` part of the object). So do something like `Parent (int a=0){...};` or call the base ctor in `Child` as `Child (const Child&): Parent(value){...}`

Comment: @Mike: Great that worked for the assignment operator. But I do get the error in the Child class for copy constructor as:   error: no matching function for call to ‘Lib::Parent::Parent()’

Comment: @Mike. That was spot on. I changed the Parent class ctor to be Parent (int a = 0) and it worked well. Marking it as complete.

Comment: @vsoftco: It makes total sense.